# What can cause a change in wave's shape - One dimensional wave

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, energy, electromagnetic-radiation, waves

what can cause a change in wave's shape of one dimensional wave moving through a rope?
It's velocity ? or the wave's length ? What can cause him change his shape.

Comment: The initial pulse determines the shape.

Comment: Let's assume that a wave is situated and you want to change his shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wave shape will depend on it initial pulse and some other factor too.
If string has a rigid end then it can form a standing wave pattern in that case you get node and antinode. Amplitude of antinode will vary from zero to some maximum value and node will be at zero amplitude.
Another possible way may be that a medium in which wave propagate, drag the wave and change its shape.